# Counting dates in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which contains a list of events. Each event has a timestamp. They are sorted by time.

```
id      time
68851   2017-11-06 17:07:09
34067   2017-11-06 17:51:53
99838   2017-11-06 18:38:58 
81212   2017-11-06 18:47:47
34429   2017-11-06 19:01:52
```

I would like to expand each row to include how many events there have been in the last hour and day. So, the above table would become (eil="events in last"):

```
id      time                   eil_hour    eli_day                   
68851   2017-11-06 17:07:09    1           1 
34067   2017-11-06 17:51:53    2           2
99838   2017-11-06 18:38:58    2           3    
81212   2017-11-06 18:47:47    3           4
34429   2017-11-06 19:01:52    3           5
```

Here is my attempt to do so in Pandas if the first table is stored in `df`:

```
def eventsInLast(date):
    ddict = {"eil_hour": 0, "eil_minute": 0}
    #loop over timedeltas
    for c, delta in [("eil_hour",timedelta(hours=1)),("eil_minute",timedelta(minutes=1))]:
        #find number of rows with dates between current row - delta and delta
        n = ((df["time"] >= (date-delta)) & (df["time"] <= date)).sum()
        ddict[c] = n
        if n==0:
            break #break if no events in last hour, since there won't be any in last minute either
    return pd.Series(ddict)

pd.concat([df,df["time"].apply(eventsInLast)],axis=1)
```

The problem is this is incredibly slow, and I am working with a large dataset. Can anyone suggest a more efficient way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
df['eil_hour'] = df.rolling('1h', on='time')['event'].sum() # sum or count??
df['eil_day'] = df.rolling('1d', on='time')['event'].sum()
```